# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "November 17, 2022 13:33"

Tags: android

I am getting a parsing exception while I am trying the following code:

```
String date="November 7, 2022 13:33";
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d,yyyy,h:mm");
Date currentdate;
currentdate=sdf.parse(date);
System.out.println(currentdate);
```

Comment: The comma is only after the day not after the year.

Comment: This is my fault. I did not see " , ". Thanks Swayangjit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format should be like following

```
MMMM d,yyyy h:mm
```

not

```
MMMM d,yyyy,h:mm
```